# Migrating from react router 3 to react router 4 - how do I convert my nested routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have nested routes like this

```
 <Route path='/' component={App}>
   <IndexRedirect to='/in' />
   <Route path='in' component={Authentication(MainPage)} routes>
   <Route path='welcome' component={Welcome}/>
  </Route>
 <Route path='*' component={NotFound}/>
</Route>
```

Most of my routes look like this:

`mysite.com/in/welcome`

I'm not sure what React Router 4 is asking for. Do I need to define all of my "child routes" inside my `MainPage` component?

Comment: mmm are you missing routes in your codeblock? `mysite.com/in/whatever` doesn't have a corresponding route in your example

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being literal to my code. I updated it to say `/welcome` to be more precise

Comment: react router 4 is much simpler concept... wherever a Route component is placed is where the component content will render.. so only put child routes inside MainPage if you want to render them inside of MainPages render